# How to capture xmpp traffic by tool

Tags: xmpp, wireshark, openfire

We are working on a project that uses Open fire(Xmpp) protocol. I have to capture that traffic(xmpp). suggest me tool and process.?
does wireshark work for xmpp traffic.?

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion only relevant if you happen to be using Smack:

If you are just trying to debug the traffic for a particular client while developing it and you happen to be using Smack as your client side library (just a guess since we are talking about openfire), then you can also make use of the Smack debug console. Adding the Java system property `-Dsmack.debugEnabled=true` will cause a debug console window to open each time an XMPP connection is established. IT shows traffic in/out and other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Wireshark works for XMPP traffic, as long as it is unencrypted.

If the connection is encrypted, you *may* be able to decrypt it by following the instructions at https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL .

Answer (score 0):

For monitors conversations and statistics of the openfire server,you can use **Monitoring Service** plugin in openfire.

For install

- Go to server web amdin panel
- Go to plugin menu
- click on available plugin
- find and install Monitoring Service plugin.